# Comparar margenes de 2 variables en un juego de carreras

Tags: javascript

Es un juego de autos donde el llegar a la línea de llegada debe salir una alerta de ganaste (aún no esta terminado)

El problema esta en la function LineaDeLlegada () más específicamente linea 47 y 48. La idea es comparar la posición del "auto" con el margen. Si este es mayor disparar la alerta de cuál auto cruzo primero la línea de llegada PERO el "auto" cruza la línea de llega y no se ejecuta la alerta

Cualquier aprendizaje para entender bien cómo lograrlo bienvenido sea o para mejorar el código

El código del juego es:

```
//Eventos
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", IniciarJuego);


//Variables
const autoRojo= document.getElementById("auto-rojo");
const autoAzul= document.getElementById("auto-azul");

let moviemientoAutoRojo= 0;
let moviemientoAutoAzul= 0;

//funciones

function IniciarJuego () {
    MoverAuto();
    LineaDeLlegada ();
    FestejoGanador();
    JugarDeNuevo ();

}

function MoverAuto () {
    //llamado a letra
    document.addEventListener("keyup",MoverAuto)

    //Muevo auto rojo
    if(event.key === "d") {
        moviemientoAutoRojo = moviemientoAutoRojo + 10;
    }
    autoRojo.style.marginLeft= moviemientoAutoRojo + "px";
    

    //Muevo auto azul
    if(event.key === "m") {
        moviemientoAutoAzul= moviemientoAutoAzul +400;
    }
    autoAzul.style.marginLeft= moviemientoAutoAzul + "px";
    
    LineaDeLlegada ();
   
}
```

Acá es donde esta el eror

```
// Error de sintaxis o código en línea 47 y 48
function LineaDeLlegada () {

    let meta = document.getElementsByClassName("pista")
     meta= parseFloat(getComputedStyle(meta).marginRight)
    let posicionAutorojo = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(autoRojo).marginRight);
    let posicionAutoAzul = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(autoAzul).marginRight);
    if (posicionAutorojo >= meta) {
        alert("Gano Rojo");
    }

    if(posicionAutoAzul >= meta ) {
        alert("Gano azul")
    }
}





function FestejoGanador () {

}

function JugarDeNuevo () {

}
```

Comment: Cuantas clases llamadas `pista` tienes en tu HTML?

Comment: Una sola clase utilizada dos veces para crear dos carriles. este el código html:


```

<!-- Carril 1 con auto rojo--> 
        <div class="pista" id="lineaPunteada">
            <div><img class="tamañoAuto" id="auto-rojo" src="AutoRojo.png" alt="Auto de carrera rojo"></div>
        </div>
        <!-- Carril 2 con auto azul--> 
        <div class="pista">
         <div><img class="tamañoAuto" id="auto-azul" src="AutoAzul.png" alt="Auto de carrera Azul"></div>
        </div> 
```

Comment: Le adjunté una respuesta, me avisa si le funcionó o si tiene problemas.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda. Las alerta dentro de los ifs se disparan apenas se abre el programa

Comment: Claro, depende si entra a uno de los `if`... ¿Tu problema se solucionó o tienes algún otro inconveniente?

Comment: Luego de analizar tu respuesta e investigando mucho la respuesta correcta es la siguiente

function LineaDeLlegada () {

    let AnchoElemntoPista= document.getElementById("lineaPunteada").getBoundingClientRect().right;
    
    let posicionAutoAzul= autoAzul.getBoundingClientRect().right;
    let posicionAutorojo= autoRojo.getBoundingClientRect().right;


    if (posicionAutorojo >= AnchoElemntoPista) {
        alert("Gano Rojo");
    }

    if(posicionAutoAzul >= AnchoElemntoPista ) {
        alert("Gano azul")
     }
}

Comment: Hola Agustin, que bueno que hayas solucionado tu problema, podrías subir tu propia respuesta para ayudar a otros que se encuentren con tu mismo problema, y de paso marcar como aceptada la  respuesta y/o comentario, que te ayudó a resolverlo (o darle un voto).

Answer (score 0):

El método `getElementsByClassName()` devuelve una colección de elementos, y como solo hay uno, debes ingresar a ese elemento así:

```
let meta = document.getElementsByClassName("pista")[0];
```

o también:

```
let meta = document.querySelector(".pista");
```

Ahora en esta línea, le estás reasignando a `meta` el valor flotante que te devuelve `getComputedStyle()`, y usas a él mismo para saber el tamaño de `marginRight`:

```
meta = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(meta).marginRight)
```

Puede que el error sea aquí, entonces vendría mejor separarlo en variables diferentes:

```
let metaRight = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(meta).marginRight);
```

Y esa variable también iría para los `if`:

```
if (posicionAutorojo >= metaRight) {
    alert("Ganó Rojo");
}
if (posicionAutoAzul >= metaRight) {
    alert("Ganó Azul");
}
```

Quedando tu función así:

```
function LineaDeLlegada() {
  let meta = document.querySelector(".pista");
  // let meta = document.getElementsByClassName("pista")[0];
  let metaRight = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(meta).marginRight);
  let posicionAutorojo = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(autoRojo).marginRight);
  let posicionAutoAzul = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(autoAzul).marginRight);
  if (posicionAutorojo >= metaRight) {
    alert("Ganó Rojo");
  }
  if (posicionAutoAzul >= metaRight) {
    alert("Ganó Azul");
  }
}
```